# Context Manager for Popen

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new in Python. I was trying a solution on Context Manager as below:
**Problem Statement:**
Define a function run_process which accepts a system command, runs the command in background and returns the result

**Solution I tried:**

```
def run_process:
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd_args) as proc:
        proc.communicate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    cmd_args_cnt = 0
    cmd_args_cnt = int(input())
    cmd_args_i = 0
    cmd_args = []
    while cmd_args_i < cmd_args_cnt:
        try:
            cmd_args_item = str(input())
        except:
            cmd_args_item = None
        cmd_args.append(cmd_args_item)
        cmd_args_i += 1

    res = run_process(cmd_args);

    if 'with' in inspect.getsource(run_process):
        f.write("'with' used in 'run_process' function definition.\n")

    if 'Popen' in inspect.getsource(run_process):
        f.write("'Popen' used in 'run_process' function definition.\n")
        f.write('Process Output : %s\n' % (res.decode("utf-8")))

    f.close()
```

**Expected Input:**
3
python
-c
print("Hello")

**Expected Output:**
'with' used in 'run_process' function definition.
'Popen' used in 'run_process' function definition.
Process Output : Hello

Answer (score 4):

```
def run_process(cmd_args):
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as p:
        out, err = p.communicate()
    return out
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
def run_process(cmd_args):
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as p:
        out, err = p.communicate() 
        return out
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Comment: This is literally the same answer as that provided by @user10754055 almost 1 year prior.

Answer (score 0):

```
def run_process(cmd_args):
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd_args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
        return proc.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: If you're posting an answer to an old question, your answer would be much better if you could provide some context as to what value your answer brings compared to the original answers.

Comment: This is almost the same exact answer provided by @user10754055 almost 1 year prior.